# How can I programmatically remove a drawer item in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

**Problem:** I am using React Native, React Navigation, and Expo In-App Purchases. The first item in my drawer is to "Unlock App" with an in-app purchase. I would like to have the user navigated back to the home screen after successful purchase of the app. When the user is navigated back to Home I would like the drawer to reflect that the "Unlock App" tab is no longer there because the app has been purchased. I'm still new to React Navigation so I'm sorry if this is stupidly simple.

**Things I've Tried:** I have done what was requested here https://aboutreact.com/how-to-hide-navigation-drawer-sidebar-option/ which is also what a lot of similar StackOverflow question suggests. That is great if I want to have a tab that is hidden from the start like after the user closes and reopens the app after the purchase, but it does not help me directly after the user purchases the app.

**Code:**

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { Feather, AntDesign, Entypo, MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { isAppPurchased } from './screens/UnlockAppFromStoreScreen';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

import Strings from './constants/strings';
import Colors from './constants/Colors';

//Skipping all the screen imports
.
.
.

var isPurchased = false;

class DrawerNavigation extends Component {  

componentDidMount(){    
  if(!isPurchased){      
   isPurchased = isAppPurchased();   
  }  
}  

toggleDrawer = () => {    //Toggle the side drawer open and closed 
  this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer(); 
}; 

 render() {    
   return (      
     <SafeAreaView        
      style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>        
      <TouchableOpacity         
       onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}        
       accessibilityRole="button"         
       accessibilityLabel={Strings.drawerMenuButtonDescription}>         
         <Feather name="menu" size={25} color="white" style={{marginLeft: 5}} />  
      </TouchableOpacity> 
</SafeAreaView>    );  }}


class Hidden extends Component {    
   render(){      
     return null;    
}}


var unlockDrawerLabel = !isPurchased? Strings.unLockAppLabel: <Hidden />;
var unlockDrawerIcon = !isPurchased? <AntDesign name="unlock" size={24} color="black" accessibilityLabel={Strings.unlockIconDescription} />: <Hidden />

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({    
   Unlock: {    
       screen: UnlockAppScreenNavigator,    
       navigationOptions: {      
          drawerLabel: unlockDrawerLabel,      
          drawerIcon: unlockDrawerIcon    
       }  
   },  
   Home: {    
       screen: MainScreenNavigator,    
       navigationOptions: {      
          drawerLabel: Strings.homeLabel,      
          drawerIcon: <Entypo name="home" size={24} color="black" accessibilityLabel={Strings.homeImageDescription}/>    
       }  
   },  
   Help: {    
      screen: HelpScreenNavigator,    
      navigationOptions: {      
         drawerLabel: Strings.helpLabel,      
         drawerIcon: <Entypo name="help-with-circle" size={24} color="black" accessibilityLabel={Strings.helpImageDescription}/>    
     }  
   },  
   About: {    
      screen: AboutScreenNavigator,    
      navigationOptions: {      
         drawerLabel: Strings.aboutLabel    
      }  
   },  
   SendFeedback: {    
      screen: SendFeedbackNavigator,    
      navigationOptions: {      
         drawerLabel: Strings.sendFeedback,      
         drawerIcon: <MaterialIcons name="feedback" size={24} color="black" accessibilityLabel={Strings.feedbackImageDescription}/>    
      }  
   }},  
{    initialRouteName: 'Home'  });



InAppPurchases.setPurchaseListener(
({responseCode, results, errorCode}) => { 
     console.log("Purchase Listener: ");  
     if(responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK){      
          results.forEach( purchase => {        
             if(!purchase.acknowledged){            
                  console.log(`Successfully purchased ${purchase.productID}`);            
                  //Unlock the app here...            
                  AsyncStorage.setItem(Strings.appPurchaseStorageItem, 'true');            
                  InAppPurchases.finishTransactionAsync(purchase, false);
                  
                  unlockDrawerIcon = <Hidden />;            
                  unlockDrawerLabel = <Hidden />;        
             }      
          });  
     }  
     else{      
       console.log(`Something went wrong: Error Code ${errorCode}`);  
     }
});

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

**isAppPurchased Function:**

```js
export async function isAppPurchased(){
   var storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Strings.appPurchaseStorageItem);
   var isPurchased = false;

   if(storedData !== null){
        isPurchased = storedData === 'true';
   }
   else{
        var purchaseHistory = await InAppPurchase.connectAsync();
        
        purchaseHistory.forEach( result => {
             isPurchased = result.acknowledged;
        });
   }

   return isPurchased;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.